# Issues binding to the click event of a Windows Forms element

Tags: winforms

I have a Windows Forms DropDown element called `tsmiSendFeedback`. I'm trying to bind to its `click` event. The method I have in place to do this is the following:

```
private static void tsmiSendFeedback_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SubmitFeedbackDialog.ShowRequestDialog();
}
```

I set the debugger in that method, run the program, click the element, and it doesn't even make it there. No error, just never hits the breakpoint. It's happening seemingly with every dropdown element in this specific dropdown, but other ones on the page work fine. They are all done in the same fashion though.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: That symptom would suggest to me that your tsmiSendFeedback spellings are inconsistent....

Comment: I've double checked, and they are the same. Also, for the other 2 elements in this specific dropdown that are acting the same way, they are consistent spelling wise as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your designer messed something up.

You need to make sure that the OnClick of that button is assigned to that event handler. You can do this by double clicking on the button again in the designer, or more reliably (if option A hasn't worked), you can go into the designer.cs file and assign the OnClick to that event manually.

In the designer.cs file, add the following:

```
tsmiSendFeedBack.Click += new EventHandler(tsmiSendFeedback_Click);
```

Comment: I think I probably just assumed it was added through the first route, and I guess it wasn't, but they forgot to add the line of code to bind it.

Comment: Yea, when the designer gets screwed up, weird things like that happen :)